# Three issues with an Arabic language document

Tags: babel, arabic

I am writing a mathematics book in Arabic Language, I face some problems which I didn't find a solution for:

1) The figures and tables captions shows the number before the text (1.2 Figure) and it should be (Figure 1.2). the picture explain more

[image]

2) The equation numbers are showing in reversed order as shown below: it is chapter 3 and therfore it should start with 3 not 16.

[image]

3) Page numbers are in Arabic not Hindi format, how can i change that?

Thanks

---

The preamble is like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper]{report} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{arabtex} 
\usepackage[arabic]{babel} 
\usepackage[LFE,LAE]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{mathtools} 
\usepackage{setspace} 
\usepackage{amsfonts} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\usepackage{lmodern} 
\usepackage{natbib} 
\usepackage{siunitx} 
\bibliographystyle{plainnat} 
\usepackage{subfiles} 
\usepackage[LFE,LAE]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{caption}
```

Comment: you are asking people what you should change but have given _no_ information about what you have. How are you typesetting this? pdftex+arabtex macros, or luatex or xetex or ....  please add a small complete document to your question that shows the problem and can be used to test answers.

Comment: \documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{arabtex}
\usepackage[arabic]{babel}
\usepackage[LFE,LAE]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage[LFE,LAE]{fontenc}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\usepackage{caption}

Comment: i am using pdflatex, with overleaf. the packages i used are above this comment. The document is 400 pages and thats why i cant add it here.

Comment: please add code to the _question_ (where you can use the `{}` button so line endings are preserved). The 400 page original document is not needed but you should post a simple one page example that people can run to see the problem.

Comment: Some general comments about your preamble: (i) Don't load packages twice (cf `fontenc`); (ii) No need to load the `amsmath` package explicitly as it's loaded automatically by the `mathtools` package; and (iii) load the `amssymb` package, which automatically loads `amsfonts`.

Comment: \documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{arabtex}
\usepackage[arabic]{babel}
\usepackage[LFE,LAE]{fontenc}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{subfiles}
%\usepackage[LFE,LAE]{fontenc}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\title{\Huge\textsc{مقدمة في علم الرياضيات  }

Comment: \begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htp]
  \centerline{\includegraphics{Figures/11}} 
    \caption{ مخطط العائد لخيار الشراء الأوروبي عند استخدام الصيغة $C=\max(S(T)-E,0)$. }
    \label{fig:Figure11}
\end{figure}
\begin{equation}
P = \max (E-S (T ),0).     
\end{equation}

\end{document}

Comment: It would be better to edit the sample code from your comments into your question, with proper formatting. What we really need is a MWE that we can copy and reproduce the bug.

Comment: You load the `mathtools` package, which allows you to change the formatting of equation tags. See [this section of the manual.](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/mathtools/mathtools.pdf#subsubsection.3.2.1)

Comment: You don’t appear to be loading `babel` with the `bidi` option, which I believe RTL languages need to work properly.

Comment: I’d also personally recommend that you use modern Unicode fonts when you can, and legacy 8-bit encodings when you have to. You might have a look at Khaled Hosny’s.